# How can I watch the complete disassembly code when open PE binary in ollydbg?

Tags: portable-executable, ollydbg

I opened `cstrike.exe`(for game Counter Strike) with ollydbg, but the disassembly code isn't complete,it starts at `01401000` and stops at `0140BFFF`(I mean it should at least start from `00000000` to be complete, and I can't say for sure whether `0140BFFF` is the exact end or just a stripped part)

```
01401000   . E8 05000000    CALL cstrike.0140100A
01401005   . E9 0A000000    JMP cstrike.01401014
0140100A   $ B9 90134101    MOV ECX,cstrike.01411390
...
0140BFFD     00             DB 00
0140BFFE     00             DB 00
0140BFFF     00             DB 00
```

How can I make OD show all the nitty-gritty details of the PE binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is nothing at 00000000

Second, OD shows one memory region in disassembly window.
Open memory window (alt+M) to see all memory regions.
Or use ctrl-G to get to desired memory address.

Comment: Virtual memory is allocated by VirtualAlloc function ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28VS.85%29.aspx ). It allocates _regions_ of memory pages - some amount of memory pages following each other.

Answer (score 0):

when you start exe file `operation system` analyze your code and put it on memory.

part of your exe tell OS size of your code ,size of your data and other information. this part is on beginning of your code and named `header section`.

also you have `code section`, `data section` , `import and export section` and `resource section`.

address of 4000 is set by header section.